# Handling a "drop" event in javascript with Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to build a board game in javascript  with Raphael, which involves having the user drag and drop some pictures. I know Raphael objects have a method **drag** that enables pictures to be dragged.

I want the user to move a piece (represented by a picture) only according to the rules. To do this, I can write a method **move** in that way (in this example, a piece can only move by one square vertically):

```
move = function (dx, dy) {
    document.getElementById("xCoord").innerHTML = dx;
    document.getElementById("yCoord").innerHTML = dy;
startSquareX = coordToSquare(this.ox);
startSquareY = coordToSquare(this.oy);
newSquareX = coordToSquare(this.ox+dx);
newSquareY = coordToSquare(this.oy+dy);
var deltaX = newSquareX - startSquareX;
var deltaY = newSquareY - startSquareY;       
if((deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY)===1) {
    this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy+dy});                       
} else {
    this.attr({x: this.ox, y: this.oy});
}}
```

The code above enables to user to move a piece in the only squares in the board that the rules allow. I would prefer to have it sightly differently: 
- the user can drag a piece wherever she wants on the board
- when the piece is dropped on a square, if the piece is moved according to the rules, then the piece is put where the user dropped it. Otherwise, it is put back on its initial square.

This is the second point I am unable to do, because I don't know how to handle the event "drop" with Raphael. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a `drop` event in in Raphael but `Element.drag` has an event handler for `onend`. That's where you define your "drop".

Refer to [this](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) demo. Notice the `up` handler (view source) that is called when element stops being dragged.

Comment: I am trying to test your answer, but apparently I am not allows to visit your demo. Are you sure it is http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.js ?

Comment: Yeah I managed to do what I wanted. Instead of putting my control in the move function, I put it into the up function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Np! Glad it helped. As a little extra,  it doesn't have to be called "up". The definition of drag is [here](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag), just make sure you send it correctly.